# Describe AR process with additive white noise using ARMA process

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, autoregressive, arma, discrete-time

Disclaimer: This is a homework problem

This is a problem from "Adaptive Filter Theory" by Haykin. Problem 2.10 (2nd edition).

**Problem**

A discrete-time stochastic process $\{x(n)\}$ that is real-valued consists of an AR process $\{u(n)\}$ and additive white noise process $\{v_2(n)\}$. The AR component is described by the difference equation

\begin{equation}
\tag 1
u(n) + \sum_{k=1}^{M}a_k u(n-k) = v_1(n)
\end{equation}

where $\{a_k\}$ are the set of AR parameters and $\{v_1(n)\}$ is a white noise process that is independent of $\{v_2(n)\}$. Show that $\{x(n)\}$ is an ARMA process described by

\begin{equation}
\tag 2
x(n) = -\sum_{k=1}^{M}{a_k x(n-k)} + \sum_{k=1}^{M}{b_k e(n-k)} + e(n)
\end{equation}

where $\{e(n)\}$ is a white noise process. How are the MA parameters $\{b_k\}$ defined? How is the variance of $e(n)$ defined?

**Attempted Solution**

Maybe there's a way to approach this in the time domain but I think I'm making some headway with this approach.

First, writing $x(n)$ in terms of the AR process and additive white noise.

\begin{equation}
\tag 3
x(n) = u(n) + v_2(n)
\end{equation}

Taking the Z-transform of (3) I get

\begin{equation}
\tag 4
X(z) = U(z) + V_2(z)
\end{equation}

Where I can express $U(z)$ using (1) as

\begin{equation}
\tag 5
U(z) = \frac{V_1(z)}{1+\sum_{k=1}^{M}{a_k z^{-k}}} = \frac{V_1(z)}{A(z)}
\end{equation}

So (4) becomes

\begin{equation}
\tag 6
X(z) = \frac{V_1(z)}{A(z)} + V_2(z)
\end{equation}

For the ARMA process described by (2) I'm looking for the following input output relation

\begin{equation}
\tag 7
\frac{X(z)}{E(z)} = \frac{B(z)}{A(z)}
\end{equation}

where $B(z) = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{M}{b_k z^{-k}}$.

Solving for $X(z)$ in (6) and relating it to (7) I get the following equation

\begin{equation}
\tag 8
\frac{E(z)B(z)}{A(z)} = \frac{V_1(z)}{A(z)} + V_2(z)
\end{equation}

I rearrange (8) and am left with the following equation

\begin{equation}
\tag 9
B(z)E(z) = V_1(z) + A(z)V_2(z)
\end{equation}

It seems in theory that I could use this relation to come up with values for $b_k, k=1,2,...,M$ but I don't know how to determine the variance of $e(n)$.

Its possible (likely) that I'm approaching this problem wrong. Does anyone have any insight into how one might go about solving this problem?

**Edit**
I think I've figured out the answer to this question but it would be nice if somebody more qualified could verify my solution.

Continuing where I left off...

Take the inverse z-transform of $(9)$ then I get

\begin{equation}
\tag {10}
\sum_{k=0}^{M}{b_k e(n-k)}=v_1(n)+\sum_{k=0}^{M}a_kv_2(n-k)
\end{equation}

Where $b_0 = a_0 = 1$

Taking the autocorrelation of both sides (square and take expectation) gives

\begin{equation}
\tag {11}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \left(\sum_{k=0}^{M}{b_k e(n-k)} \right)^2 \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( v_1(n)+\sum_{k=0}^{M}a_kv_2(n-k) \right)^2 \right]
\end{equation}

The cross terms cancel because the noise is all uncorrelated so I get

\begin{equation}
\tag {12}
\sigma_e^2 \sum_{k=0}^{M}{b_k^2} = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 \sum_{k=0}^{M}{a_k^2}
\end{equation}

Where $\sigma_e^2 = \mathbb{E}[e(n)^2]$, and $\sigma_k^2 = \mathbb{E}[v_k(n)], k=1,2$.

**As long as this relation in $(12)$ holds then I should be good right?**

So I can choose to define $\sigma_e^2$ however I want, then define $b_k, k=1,...,M$ such that

\begin{equation}
\tag {13}
\sum_{k=0}^{M}{b_k^2} = \frac{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 \sum_{k=0}^{M}{a_k^2}}{\sigma_e^2}
\end{equation}

Alternatively, I could define $b_k, k=1,...,M$ however I want and compute $\sigma_e^2$ as

\begin{equation}
\tag {14}
\sigma_e^2 = \frac{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 \sum_{k=0}^{M}{a_k^2}}{\sum_{k=0}^{M}{b_k^2}}
\end{equation}